# How to use multiple dimension and metric values in google adsense version api 1.4

Tags: google-api, adsense, adsense-api

When generating reports from google adsense management api v 1.4 can how listed here : 
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/reports/generate

I checked out the metrics and dimension given here : 
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/metrics-dimensions

I tried to pass these values in request and its working fine for me :

```
startDate=2015-07-07&
endDate=2015-07-12&
dimension=AD_UNIT_NAME&
metric=AD_REQUESTS_CTR
```

But how should i pass multiple metric values ? 
for example if i want metric values :

```
AD_REQUESTS_RPM , 
AD_REQUESTS_RPM ,
CLICKS , 
EARNINGS etc
```

I tried to separate them with normal and url-encoded values of

```
":" 
","
" " (space)
```

But nothing works for me , i am getting this error :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidParameter",
    "message": "Invalid value 'AD_REQUESTS_CTR:AD_REQUESTS_RPM'. Values must match the following regular expression: '[a-zA-Z_]+'",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "metric[0]"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value 'AD_REQUESTS_CTR:AD_REQUESTS_RPM'. Values must match the following regular expression: '[a-zA-Z_]+'"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so i found the solution to pass multiple metric and dimension value and i think its a really poor api design by google adsense team .

This is how it works :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts/pub-423423423432/reports?alt=json&
startDate=2015-07-07&
endDate=2015-07-12&
dimension=AD_UNIT_NAME&
metric=AD_REQUESTS_RPM& 
metric=AD_REQUESTS_RPM&
metric=CLICKS& 
metric=EARNINGS
```

Comment: Hope this helps someone else. I got here by searching for same question but using the API request.The answer here is for manual url creation. But for API requests, multiple dimensions or metrics can be requested by enclosing them in square brackets so it is list of values eg dimension=['DOMAIN_NAME','DATE']